# is it possible to use jq to calculate derivative?

Tags: arrays, json, jq, derivative

I have initial json data, as array of collected data points for graph (arrays) - first is a timestamp, second is some everincreasing value, collected over time (lets say, h2o level)

```
[[1,5.5],[2,5.6],[3,5.9],[4,6.9]]
```

I want to find derivative of second changing value, over time, in jq.

so with given offset = -1 it should produce output

```
[[2,0.1],[3,0.3],[4,1.0]]
```

How can i do that?

i tried

```
$ echo "[[1,5.5],[2,5.6],[3,5.9],[4,6.9]]" | jq '[[.[1][0],.[1][1]-.[0][1]]]'
[
  [
    2,
    0.09999999999999964
  ]
]
```

but then if Ill try to put it inside `map` operation - I am stuck here - I have only current value, but i do not have any previous, to substraract it from current...

Comment: What does _so with given offset = -1_ mean? Can you post sample outputs for other values of offset?

Comment: @Inian by how much previous values offsets from current. in simpliest case it lags 1 sample. but in general you may want bigger amounts. for -2 meaningful result would obviously be [[3, 0.4],[4,1.3]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate two subsets based on the offset, then subtract each corresponding element using `transpose` and `map` (beware of floating point imprecision):

```bash
(-1) as $offset
| [.[-$offset:], .[:$offset]] | transpose | map(.[0][1] -= .[1][1] | .[0])
```

```json
[[2,0.09999999999999964],[3,0.3000000000000007],[4,1]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2OCX2CcRn0P)

---

Alternatively, use a `range` to iterate over the indices, and build the new array successively:

```bash
(-1) as $offset
| [range(-$offset; length) as $i | [.[$i][0], .[$i][1] - .[$i + $offset][1]]]
```

```json
[[2,0.09999999999999964],[3,0.3000000000000007],[4,1]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1-oey50L0d9)

Comment: Awesome. I liked second variant more, because it is more easily readable by beginners. Btw, is there any query benchmark tool? (given an input and query, run query million times, measure time, estimate performance of query to compare both variants, for eaxmple?)

Comment: @xakepp35 Using [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) and sample data created with `jq -n '[range(1000000) as $t | [$t, now]]'` revealed after 10 runs each that the `range` variant is 1.95 ± 0.12 times faster than the `transpose` variant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic "derivative" function yielding a declarative one-line solution (apart of course from the `def` itself):

```
  # Input: an array
  # `delta` should be a non-negative integer, typically 1;
  # p is the jq path expression to the quantity within an item, e.g. `.`
  def derivative(delta; p):
    . as $in
    | [ range(delta; length) as $i
        | .[$i]
        | (p = ($in[$i] | p) - ($in[$i - delta] | p)) ];

  derivative(1; .[1])
```

Comment: GJ, +1 for your input, good to have as an example of `| p ` idea..